# Fail with ng-repeat when pushing

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem with angular, this is my code

HTML

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Insertar presupuesto</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#seleccionarp">Buscar producto</button>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div id="seleccionarp" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Seleccione su producto</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <label for="Buscar cliente  ">Buscar producto:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="buscarproducto" ng-model="busqueda[queryBy]" value="" placeholder="Buscar" />
                            <div>
                                <table class="table table-hover">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Descripcion</th>
                                        <th>Color</th>
                                        <th>Talle</th>
                                        <th>Stock</th>
                                        <th>Precio</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tbody ng-repeat="emp in posts | filter:busqueda">
                                        <tr ng-click="comprar(emp)" data-dismiss="modal">
                                            <td>{{emp.nombre_producto}}</td>
                                            <td>{{emp.color}}</td>
                                            <td>{{emp.talle}}</td>
                                            <td>{{emp.stock}}</td>
                                            <td>{{emp.precio | currency}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre del producto</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody ng-repeat="p in carrito track by $index">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_producto[]" value="{{p.id_producto}}" ng-model="p.id_producto" class="form-control">
                    <input type="hidden" name="color[]" value="{{p.color}}" ng-model="p.color" class="form-control">
                    <input type="hidden" name="talle[]" value="{{p.talle}}" ng-model="p.talle" class="form-control">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="nombre_producto[]" ng-model="p.nombre_producto" class="form-control">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" name="stock[]" ng-model="p.stock" value="1" onClick="this.select();" class="form-control">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="precio[]" ng-model="p.precio" onClick="this.select();" class="form-control" value="">
                        </td>
                        <td>{{p.stock * p.precio | currency}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove($index)">Eliminar</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <h2>Total:${{total()}}</h2>
            <input type="hidden" name="total_remito" value="{{total()}}">
            <button type="submit" name="button">guardar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

AngularJS

```js
app.controller("ctrlremitos", function($scope, $http) {

$scope.posts = [];

$scope.carrito = [];

$scope.clienteasignado = [];

$scope.clientes = [];

$scope.busqueda = {}

$scope.busquedaclientes = {}

$scope.queryBy = '$'

$scope.newPost = {};

$http.get(base_url + "venta/get_productos").success(function(data, timeout) {
    $scope.posts = data;
}).error(function(err) {})

$http.get(base_url + "venta/get_clientes").success(function(data) {
    $scope.clientes = data;
}).error(function(err) {})

$scope.comprar = function(_item, index) {
    $scope.carrito.push(_item)
}

$scope.asignarcliente = function(_item) {
    $scope.clienteasignado.push(_item)
}

$scope.remove = function(index) {
        $scope.carrito.splice(index, 1);
    },

    $scope.total = function() {
        var total = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.carrito, function(p) {
            total += p.stock * p.precio;
        })
        return total;
    }

});
```

The problem is that when I select a product, does the push but the value is always the value of the stock, what I want is that when you do that push you change the stock value always by 1. Another thing I notice is that when Change the value in the field "stock", also changed in the array of the search for products, I do not know what to do :( I've been trying to make this work correctly for many days, I hope they will light the way.

regards

https://github.com/outthesystem/facturacion-codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. My problem was the two-bind. Note that if you used this expression "::" in the given variable it just does a-bind, then in the "stock" field use ng-init with value 1.

https://github.com/outthesystem/facturacion-codeigniter/commit/5c4e8737d0e0b1732ba127e60fb46f1065344e03

Answer (score 2):

"$scope.total" is a function, not a scope variable.
Hence two-way binding won't work in this scenario until and unless you make an explicit call.
To make it work:
do the following changes on controller and HTML.
Controller changes:

```
$scope.total = 0;

$scope.comprar = function(_item, index) {
    $scope.carrito.push(_item);
    $scope.calculateTotal(); //Make an explicit call to calculation method
}

$scope.calculateTotal = function()
{
     angular.forEach($scope.carrito, function(p) {
            $scope.total += p.stock * p.precio;
        })
};
```

HTML change:

```
<h2>Total:${{total}}</h2>
            <input type="hidden" name="total_remito" value="{{total}}">
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think I'm not making myself understand, I attached an image to see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

i can see that is not English in your Html page but whatever if i understood your bug is you are trying to push something that's not actually in your `DOM`

```
$scope.asignarcliente = function(_item) {
$scope.clienteasignado.push(_item)
}
```

What is `$scope.clienteasignado` ??? ; the actual list that your are displaying i is named `$scope.posts` for products correct me if am wrong so if that's the list of products to push in it you need to right it that way

```
$scope.asignarcliente = function() {
$scope.posts.push(emp);
}
```

ps this function also not called in the `DOM` your just defining a button

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="asignarcliente()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
```

i hope i manipulated the right item and i hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think I'm not making myself understand, I attached an image to see what happens.

Comment: is for other push, Where the client is selected